# Can i pass a variable in a route in javascript in nodejs.I am using query method

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I have the value of _id stored in a variable.

A=_id    (A has the value)

How to pass to a route as a query parameter?

eg:-  http://localhost:3000/create?v=A   (I want to pass the value stored in A)

but it takes  value of v as literal A and not the value in A

Comment: You are hardcoding A not value of A, can you add your js function also?

Answer (score 2):

Try out this way , in your route at node side ,

`At angular side` : http://localhost:3000/create/"+A ;

though the same route at `node side`  : `app.get('/create/:id' , (callback));`

Therefore you can access that `params` is nodejs like `req.body.params`

This will help you to figure out your problem .

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a request string or a variable

```
let A = 'some value'
let url = `http://localhost:3000/create?v=${A}`
```

then call the request.